# Drag 'n' drop algorithm

Tags: javascript

This [page](https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop) describes a drag-'n'-drop algorithm.

Looking only at the first snippet of code (which the article continually improves upon), it says it's important we use `document` in `document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);`.

Is this because if we were to use `ball`, there's a chance we might move the cursor so fast the cursor might leave the box-model of the ball before `mousemove` would have a chance to execute again? We wouldn't be moving the mouse over `ball` so `mousemove` wouldn't re-fire.

Comment: I would assume so - and it's always better to use `document` and then check the location of the event, to detect it globally and then filter out unwanted results.

Comment: "Algorithm" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Dai I agree however that's the terminology used in the website.

Comment: @Dai What's your definition?

Comment: I don't consider homomorphisms of the identity function as algorithms.

Comment: @Dai Would you mind offering a positive definition of an algorithm instead of what it's not?

Comment: @tonitone120 _Strictly speaking_, any well-defined sequence of instructions is an "algorithm", including an empty set of instructions and trivial sets of instructions - however *qualitatively* and in-practice (and especially in everyday conversion between programmers) the term is reserved to describe a non-trivial sequence. However it isn't useful to describe something like `void AnAlgorithm() { return; }` as "an algorithm"  even though strictly speaking it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this because if we were to use ball, there's a chance we might move the cursor so fast the cursor might leave the box-model of the ball before mousemove would have a chance to execute again?

Yes.

This will happen if you drag an object upwards when your drag-point is also the top row of pixels of the object.

This is *less likely* to happen if you drag a larger object from its centre and your computer has a mouse with a high poll-rate *and* a high display refresh rate *and* the browser is capable of processing OS-provided input events rapidly - so if you're a front-end dev  using a high-end gaming machine (with a 1000Hz USB mouse and a 120Hz+ display) may not notice the problem compared to someone using a 100Hz mouse on a 30Hz display (which is a thing: many people run 4K displays over HDMI 1.x which can only run 4K at 30Hz).

Another scenario is when the user is using an *absolute* pointing device, such as a touch-screen or graphics tablet in absolute-mode (aka "pen mode" for Wacom) rather than relative-mode (aka "mouse mode" for Wacom) - if the user "drags" an object to somewhere else on the screen by only tapping the destination location with their finger (or by moving the stylus vertically outside the detection zone) then there will only be 1 `mousemove` event which will not be captured by `ball` at all.

Comment: I like the point about a graphics tablet - very interesting! (good luck on 100k :D)